EAS Build Stuck at "Compressing Project Files"
I am attempting to build my Expo project. I am logged into my EAS account and have distribution certificate and provisioning profile set up.
When I run:
sudo eas build --platform ios
It returns "Compressing Project Files" and has been stuck for an hour.

I have been waiting an hour, but there is not much I can do. I noticed some people online saying to run git init  which I did, but the project still is stuck at "Compressing Project Files". Is this something that should take an hour?

Hello, how did you fix it?
